# Index levels doubled when using groupby/apply on a multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when using a `groupby`/`apply` chain on a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame`: The resulting data frame contains the grouped level(s) twice!

Example data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0]),
                      index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]))

     a  b
1 3  1  6
  4  2  7
  5  3  8
2 3  4  9
  4  5  0
  5  6  0
```

In this example, I simply sum over the rows (I actually have another function, but one that also accepts and returns a dataframe):

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

And it gives me the following result:

```
1  1  3     7
      4     9
      5    11
2  2  3    13
      4     5
      5     6
dtype: int64
```

So now I have three index levels, with the one grouped by doubled. When I group by both levels, the whole multiindex in doubled:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))

1  3  1  3     7
   4  1  4     9
   5  1  5    11
2  3  2  3    13
   4  2  4     5
   5  2  5     6
dtype: int64
```

If I set `as_index=False`, I still get another index level, containing ascending numbers:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))

0  1  3     7
1  1  4     9
2  1  5    11
3  2  3    13
4  2  4     5
5  2  5     6
dtype: int64
```

Is this intended behavior? How can I avoid that another index level is created? Do I have to remove it by hand every time I do a groupby/apply operation?

Comment: I think this is a quirk of having multi-indices here, as an aside what's wrong with `df.sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: My actual function that I apply looks different. I just used the sum here to show the effect of a function that takes a dataframe and returns a dataframe ("case 2" in the documentation of apply).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's also the `group_keys` option which leaves only the `MultiIndex` of the `Series` returned by the `.sum(axis=1)` applied to the individual chunks:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0]),
                  index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]))

print(df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))

1  3     7
   4     9
   5    11
2  3    13
   4     5
   5     6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do it! In my opinion, this groupby argument should be set to False by default.